# remove unused dependency form .lockfile

Tags: gradle, lockfile

I plan to delete one unused dependency from my .lockfile, but after manually delete it I got an error "Resolved 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.2.17' which is not part of the dependency lock state". I just want to delete one dependency and running --write-locks break my application. Anyone know a way how to delete just one dependency from lock file or how to resolve above error? Thanks (I tried 1) clean build 2) delete all cache 3) clean build with --refresh-dependencies)